# How to override jar inside of Jboss 5.1 lib/endorsed directory?

Tags: java, jboss, jboss5.x, ear, xalan

We need to have the newest version of the Xalan/Serialize/Xerces jar files run inside our ear. The version inside of Jboss's 5.1 lib/endorsed directory are being loaded first when we run our application code and subsequently get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`'s.

I've read articles like this one: http://www.openscope.net/2010/07/15/setting-up-a-jboss-instance-v5-x-class-loading/

I've added a jboss-app.xml file to my meta-inf directory that got packaged into my ear. Here is what i've stuck in there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC
        "-//JBoss//DTD Java EE Application 5.0//EN"
        "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-app>  
  <loader-repository>  
  org.apache.xalan:archive=servicebroker-enterprise.ear
     <loader-repository-config>  
     java2ParentDelegation=false  
     </loader-repository-config>  
  </loader-repository>  
</jboss-app>
```

When I have that code in place my Ear isn't loaded into jboss. I see it find the ear, then just move onto other ears without loading it. I've turned on debug logging and don't see a single error or mention about why it didn't get loaded.

Why would my ear not be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to sync versions of your's Xalan/Serialize/Xerces and JBoss's one. 
First of all, try just replace JBoss one with new one, maybe it will work. Another way, consider upgrade of your JBoss to the new version that will use newest Xalan/Serialize/Xerces. Changing behaviour of the class loading process will introduce you new problems, AFAIC.

Comment: Yea, those are the options we had tried. Just dumping in the new xalan, serialize, xerces libraries into jboss causes jboss to not run. :) Changing class loading process did introduce other issues with loading jax-ws webservices in general. Overall this is a bad situation...